# Neo4j 4.x gremlin support

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I have an application which loads some external data based on gremlin.
I want to use it to load the data into a Neo4j database.
I saw that there was partial support for gremlin in previous versions but couldn't find any solution for latest version.
I'll be happy to hear if it is still possible and how can it be done.

Comment: Have you already looked [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#neo4j-gremlin)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point, TinkerPop expects to support 3.4.11 in its future 3.5.0 release ([here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/98956ea76153d28b1241a9b23bd79ae6cc6f4d6c/neo4j-gremlin/pom.xml#L120)) which is yet several months away. For TinkerPop to support 4.0 it would need a fresh release of the `neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl` to be released with that version. It seems an issue has been created for that [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl/issues/18).