# Neo4J - Gremlin Support

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I did a bit research but need to clarify some things regarding neo4j gremlin support.

I want to use tinkerpop-gremlin with neo4j db. I saw this link

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#neo4j-gremlin

from this I understand that it is possible but regarding last versions, it is slow. Does it support neo4j 5.x versions for example? ([Neo4j 4.x gremlin support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923151/neo4j-4-x-gremlin-support))

Another very important thing is if I'd continue to use my lots of groovy script with neo4j db.

Also is it easy to migrate traversal api from gremlin queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [a quick search](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/125e5bf4560546c9727dd25ff4d590f34c7d625b/neo4j-gremlin/pom.xml#L216), it seems the Gremlin support for Neo4j is currently at Neo4j 3.4, which has reached end of life quite a long time ago.

I'd say that Neo4j 4 and 5 do not support Gremlin at the moment and that seems unlikely to change in the near future?

Comment: I am not very experienced in these areas so this may sound silly but I want to ask, what would you say about the difficulties using traversal api if I want to use that instead of gremlin?

Comment: When it comes to Neo4j, Cypher (possibly augmented with extra procedures like the ones from APOC: https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/) is a good default approach.
You can always fine-tune the query with EXPLAIN/PROFILE to optimize it.
There are fewer and fewer cases where the traversal API is actually needed.